# Redirecting to a VF page from a VF page within the standard Lightning context

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I have a Visualforce page being called in LEX via a button/action on the record. The page is straightforward as shown below:

```
<apex:page id="CTISGenerateVF" lightningStylesheets="true" controller="CTISGenerateController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" action="{!generateDocuments}">
   <apex:form id="form1">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!backToRecord}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

The controller then calls a couple of other VF pages that generates a PDF and CSV file. Here's a snippet of the controller code:

```
    public PageReference generateDocuments() {
    PageReference pageRef;
    List<ContentVersion> listCV = new List<ContentVersion>();
    List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

    try {
        String dateTimeStamp = System.now().format('ddMMyyyy hh:mm:ss').replace(' ', '_').replace(':', '');

        // Generate CSV file
        PageReference pageRefCSV = new PageReference('/apex/CTISGenerateCSVVF?id=' + this.ctisId);
        Blob csvBody = (!test.isRunningTest() ? pageRefCSV.getContent() : Blob.valueOf('test'));
        ContentVersion cvCSV = new ContentVersion();
        cvCSV.VersionData = csvBody;
        cvCSV.Title = 'FoneZone_' + dateTimeStamp + '.csv';
        cvCSV.PathOnClient = 'FoneZone_' + dateTimeStamp + '.csv';
        listCV.add(cvCSV);

        // Generate PDF file
        PageReference pageRefPDF = new PageReference('/apex/CTISGeneratePDFVF?id=' + this.ctisId);
        Blob pdfBody = (!test.isRunningTest() ? pageRefPDF.getContentAsPDF() : blob.valueOf('test'));
        ContentVersion cvPDF = new ContentVersion();
        cvPDF.VersionData = pdfBody;
        cvPDF.Title = 'FoneZone_' + dateTimeStamp + '.pdf';
        cvPDF.PathOnClient = 'FoneZone_' + dateTimeStamp + '.pdf';
        listCV.add(cvPDF);

        // Insert ContentVersion list
        insert listCV;
```

I am having an error when the context shifts to the VF pages, getting an Internal Server Error with the following message in the Console:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://xxx.lightning.force.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://XXX.visual.force.com').

Not sure how to go about next - are there any other options to make this work other than rewriting the VF pages into Lightning? Thanks.